# CRC-16 and primitive polynomials

Tags: crc, crc16

I am trying to calculate the maximal data block length of `CRC-16`. It is not clear to me if the polynomial `0x8005` is a primitive polynomial.

Is `CRC-16` using a primitive polynomial or not?

Answer (score 2):

That polynomial, x<sup>16</sup>+x<sup>15</sup>+x<sup>2</sup>+1, is not primitive. x+1 divides it (modulo 2).

Comment: ...and the easiest way to verify this is substitute in x=1 into x^16+x^15+x^2+1 = 0 (modulo 2).